# What has happened to less in Twitter Bootstrap on Initializr.com?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, initializer

I just kickstarted a new project with Initializr. First I realized that the options for the stylesheet was removed and later I realized that Twitter Bootstrap doesn't come with LESS as default Stylesheet as well.

Did I miss something? I really liked it that I had the whole package without any configuration.

I tried to google this topic but I couldn't find anything related to it. Someone knows the background why LESS isn't part of neither Bootstrap nor Initializr?

Kind regards,
Marvin

Comment: Whole package without any configuration? Also, the less files are still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Initializr > Bootstrap only the CSS files are included. Same thing when you download the ZIP-file from the Twitter Bootstrap homepage (big blue button).

But: the full package from GitHub Repo stil contains everything: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap – You might donwload a zip or clone it from there. It also contains JS tests and the full docs and more.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit surprising.  I always started with an initializr/bootstrap bundle, and enjoyed having the LESS files.

I dug a little bit on github and found the [author's comments on why he made the decision](https://github.com/verekia/initializr/issues/65#issuecomment-8229564):

In the comment he states:

> I removed the Less option mostly because:
>
> - Less is more buggy than Sass (around 200 open issues) and has less features
> - People are confused about less.js, which is a terrible bad practice when used client-side inproduction
> - At this point, making people use Less is like making people use Mootools instead of jQuery.   Sass won the fight, and having multiple tools doing the same thing is not good for us. Just   use the best one to make the community grow as much as possible.

Comment: I will go on record though and say that Ive never liked the idea of bundling less.js in with an html5 bundle. It always seemed awkward. So the decision probably makes sense in the long run.

Comment: If Bootstrap comes with Less, it's not Initializr's job to decide whether or not we should use Less. Why can't it just be an option the way it's always been?

Answer (score 0):

OK, for all that actually liked the way it was before, I found a mirror website of the old one, including the less docs:

http://bootstrap.lesscss.ru/scaffolding.html